# Encoding.UTF8.GetString Parse Error?

Tags: c#, sockets, utf-8, tcp, unity-game-engine

```
// test code
void Start()
{
    // bytes is get from server with NetworkStream.Read()
    byte[] bytes = { 0xe9, 0xba, 0xbb, // 麻
                     0xe9, 0xa3, 0x8e, // 风
                     0xe4, 0xbe, 0x8f, // 侏
                     0xe5, 0x84, 0x92, // 儒
                     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
                     0x00, 0x00, 0x31, 
                     0x32, 0x00, 0x00, 
                     0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    // print: 麻风侏儒
    Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
}
```

why last 12 bytes not parsed , and how `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` deal with UTF-8 bytes, i mean how does it figure whether this is a Chinese character or a ascii character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is being parsed.  But the resulting string has embedded nulls in it so it will not print/display properly.

Try this:

```
String MyString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

char[] MyChars = MyString.ToArray();
```

MyChars has everything.